# What State/Binding do I need to use?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I want to create a `Timer` that is showing in a `Slider`.
I got this Code:

```
struct CustomSlider : View {
    @State var value: Double = 0.0
    init() {
        let thumbImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
        UISlider.appearance().setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value)
    }
}
```

```
struct MusicPlayerView: View {
    @State var value: Double = 0.0
    
    let timer = Timer
        .publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
            CustomSlider()
.onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    guard let player = audioManager.player else {return}
                    value = player.currentTime
                }
    }
}
```

How do I pass the value from `MusicPlayerView` to `CustomSlider`? I tried using `@Binding`in the `CustomSlider`but then it gives me the error:

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

in `CustomSlider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `@Binding` you need to update your `init`:

```
struct CustomSlider : View {
    @Binding var value: Double
    init(value: Binding<Double>) {
        self._value = value
        let thumbImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
        UISlider.appearance().setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value)
    }
}
```

And in `MusicPlayerView`:

```
struct MusicPlayerView: View {
    @State var value: Double = 0.0
    
    let timer = Timer
        .publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
            CustomSlider(value: $value)
.onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    guard let player = audioManager.player else {return}
                    value = player.currentTime
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the job. Atleast I know I was thinking the right way using Binding

Comment: If I answered your question, could you please mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark button> Have a great day!